# If someone gets a startup visa to the UK can their spouse work?

Tags: uk-visa

I can't find any information https://www.gov.uk/start-up-visa/your-partner-and-children is mum on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Summary (Jan 2022)**: Yes, the dependent partner of a UK Start-up visa holder is allowed to work, subject to some exceptions (which applies to majority of work visas).

---

According to the Immigration Rules (last updated 4 Jan 2022), in particular [Immigration Rules Appendix Start-up](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-start-up), the dependent partner of a UK Start-up visa holder is allowed to work if they are themselves granted a visa (emphasis and correction on the text formatting around SU 22.3(a) my own):

> **Period and conditions of grant for a dependent partner and dependent child on the Start-up route**
>
> SU 22.1. A partner will be granted permission which ends on the same date as their partner’s permission on the Start-up route
>
> SU 22.2. [...]
>
> SU 22.3. The grant will be subject to all the following conditions:
>
> > (a) no access to public funds; and
> > (b) **work (including self-employment and voluntary work) permitted; except for employment as a professional sportsperson, including as a sports coach;** and
> > (c) study is permitted, subject to the ATAs [sic] condition in Appendix ATAS; and
> > (d) if Part 10 applies the applicant will be required to register with the police.

Comment: Well, I would've never looked for this under a section titled "Eligibility requirements". Thanks.

Comment: TBF my go to method is "Show all sections" followed by a Ctrl+F on certain keywords - I do agree it is odd for such provision to be listed under the eligibility requirements section!